# How to update TreeTableView without pressing "enter" button

Tags: java, javafx

I'm using javaFx and have TreeTableView with 2 TreeTableColumn:

```
TreeTableView<MesssageField> treeTableView;
TreeTableColumn<MesssageField,String> fieldColumn;
TreeTableColumn<MesssageField,String> valueColumn;
```

In the initialize method I have the following code:

```
valueColumn.setCellFactory( TextFieldTreeTableCell.forTreeTableColumn() );
        fieldColumn.setCellValueFactory( p -> p.getValue().getValue().getFieldNameProperty());
        valueColumn.setCellValueFactory(p -> p.getValue().getValue().getFieldValueProperty());
```

When the user wants to type data in the table, he must press on "Enter".
How can I edit the code, in order to assist the user to insert data without pressing on "Enter"

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to save the data without pressing `Enter`? If yes, what do you want to use to save data?

Comment: when the user write the data into the table, he must click on "Enter" button, I want to change it, that when click on other cell (for example) the data the user  click on the previous cell will be saved